# Data Validation Dependent on Cell Value

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have spreadsheet that I require data validation to only display the relevant information on one table, depending on the value on another table

In column B on Inbound tab, I have a list of codes & in column C I have another set of codes. The codes in both of these columns can be repeated multiple times over the course of the sheet.

On Conversion tab, I have in column A, a data validation with the list of those codes in column B (Inbound tab), in column C (Conversion tab), I need the data validation to show only those that match the codes in column A, from column C in the Inbound tab.

[image: Inbound Tab]

[image: Conversion Tab]

I have tried using OFFSET & INDEX / MATCH functions, but to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

In the data validation you want your formula to read:

`=OFFSET( [first cell of codes],,,COUNTA( [column of codes]) - [# of nonblank cells in that column],1)`

Say you had a table range from A1:A4 with headers. You would input in the data validation:

`=OFFSET( $A$2,,, COUNTA($A:$A)-1,1)`

This looks are the first data cell, and doesn't count down or over any rows/columns because we skip those inputs. Then for the height we're counting using counta how many non-blanks cells there are. This tells excel from cell A2, count down x amount of cells to the bottom of the range, I subtracted 1 because of the header row we don't want included (similar to what you may have in your sheet). Then, we're only taking that first column so we use 1. This is 'an unstable' formula, so be mindful of what data you have above and below this column if you approach the problem this way. I like to use a `Sort` & `Unique` functions to produce an organized list elsewhere on the workbook so I don't need to worry about other inputs messing with this formula.